# Swift - iCarousal using UiView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, icarousel

I am working on a food ordering app and creating the menu page using iCarousel with cards like [Card Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjj04.png). As I want the buttons in cards to add or delete product and scroll view for product description. So can anyone help me out as how can I implement this feature or is there any other alternative for this ??

Answer (score 1):

Download the iCarousel project: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Add the `iCarousel.h` and `iCarousel.m` files to your Swift project.

Xcode will prompt you to add a bridge-header. Select ok

In the bridge-header:

```
#import "iCarousel.h"
```

Add a `UIView` to your storyboard. Set the type to `iCarousel`.

Connect the view to your code.

```
@IBOutlet var carouselView: iCarousel!
```

Add the `iCarouselDelegate` and `iCarouselDataSource` to your view controller.

Then add the following methods:

```
func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return 1//Or however many views you want
}

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    //Create a UIView programmatically and return it
}
```

Lastly, add the following in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`:

```
carouselView.delegate = self
carouselView.dataSource = self
carouselView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot ... But how can i have multiple views with buttons (2 or 3 on each view) and each with different functionality ?? So I was thinking of designing views independently and then using them with iCarousel, is it even possible as I am completely new to this and having not a single clue about its implementation

Comment: Create an array called returnViews. Add all of your views to the array. Then `return returnViews[index]`

Comment: Its giving me this error- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Comment: To debug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu